# Does the Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK allow for Pronunciation assessment?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I only see it in the REST API...which works but hoping to have more options. Am I missing it somewhere in the SDK? The classes are a bit confusing there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We are continuously working to improve this service. Currently, Pronunciation Assessment is only available via REST API. Feel free to share your feedback on the [User Voice Forum](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/912208-speech-service) so you and others can up-vote to enable the product team prioritize this feature. Thanks.